# Get device Id from Mobile First

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I added the above code in `main.js` inside the `wlCommonInit` function.

```
   var options = {
                onSuccess: succ,
                onFailure: fail
        };
        WL.Device.getID(options);
        function succ(data) {
            alert('succ ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        }

        function fail() {
            alert('fail');
        }
```

But I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: WL.Device.getID is not a function` error in desktop web console.

Is it possible to add this code in other js files?

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, this API method is *not available* in Desktop browsers. It is available only for mobile devices: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23getID

> Supported environments: Android, iOS, WindowsPhone8, Blackberry, Blackberry10.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Idan

Answer (score 1):

Since you see it in Desktop web console, I take it you are trying out Desktop Browser environment/ Mobile Web app.

This API is not applicable in either case. It works only on Android, iOS, WindowsPhone8, Blackberry, Blackberry10. For more details refer to [KnowledgeCenter](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23getID?lang=en).